# How to search relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models which are related. I am trying to do a search in orders and only display the actual search results instead of ALL orders of the category and user in which the order was found.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('report_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('time');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->integer('issue_number');
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

So, what I WANT to achieve is the following. What I WANT to be displayed is:

OrderController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $keyword = request('search') ?? null;
    $orders = Order::query()->whereIn('user_id', $user->id)->whereIn('category_id', $category->id)
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->when($keyword, function ($query) use ($keyword) {
                $query->where('first_name' , 'LIKE' , "%{$keyword}%");
            });
        })->latest()->paginate(25);
    return view('Admin.orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

Order.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function report()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Report::class);
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Comment: You say *So, what I WANT to achieve is the following. What I WANT to be displayed is:* and then share your code but do not actually share WHAT you want to achieve. Sidenote, from your title I think you may be looking for [querying relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Yes, I want to do something like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right you want to apply filter to your related table. For that kind of operation you can use `whereHas` or `whereRelation` methods of eloquent.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%');
})->get();
```

or

```
$posts = Post::whereRelation(
    'comments', 'created_at', '>=', now()->subHour()
)->get();
```

`comments` is related column.

For more information check [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).